# R if function for multiple arguments

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I this function

```
gillespied4 <- function (N, T = 100, dt = 1, ...) 
{
  tt = 0
  n = T%/%dt
  x = N$M
  S = t(N$Post - N$Pre)
  u = nrow(S)
  v = ncol(S)
  xmat = matrix(ncol = u, nrow = n)
  i = 1
  target = 0
  repeat {
    h = N$h(x, tt, ...)
    h0 = sum(h)
    if (h0 < 1e-10) 
      tt = 1e+99
    else tt = tt + rexp(1, h0)
    while (tt >= target) {
      xmat[i, ] = x
      i = i + 1
      target = target + dt
      if ((i*dt) ==c(seq(0,30000,2000))){
        x[4] = x[4]+(10000/15000)
      }
      if (i > n) 
        return(ts(xmat, start = 0, deltat = dt))
    }
    j = sample(v, 1, prob = h)
    x = x + S[, j]
  }
}
```

, and I am having an issue with the line

```
  if ((i*dt) ==c(seq(0,30000,2000))){
    x[4] = x[4]+(10000/15000)
  }
```

And the error I am getting is

```
In if ((i * dt) == c(seq(0, 30000, 2000))) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I know the problem is that the `if` function doesn't work for multiple values. After searching through stackoverflow most of the answers to this type of question suggest using `elseif` function or using `|` but I don't think these apply in this case.

I was wondering if there was any way to overcome this

Comment: your current if statement likely produces a boolean vector, so you can just wrap it in `all`. `if (all(i == x)) ... `

Comment: maybe you want `%in%` rather than `==` ?

Comment: @erocoar hmmm I've just tried this and it doesn't seem to work. I know I could do it by doing `if((i*dt)==2000){...}` then `if((i*dt)==4000){...}` etc it will work but that is very cumbersome.

Comment: Ok my bad, I didn't see the `while` :) @BenBolker is probably right then with using `%in%`

Comment: @BenBolker Whilst I think what you put is correct, when I apply this function it's saying I am getting negative probabilities, which I don't understand

Comment: actually that doesn't matter now, I think it was just the values I was using. Thank you